# List of all functions used in python program as string

Tags: python, string, function

How can we find all the functions in a python program??? for eg.

**Input**

```
def func1:
  #doing something

def func2:
  #doing something

def func3:
  #doing something
```

**Output**

```
{'func1' , 'func2' , 'func3'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all functions in the global scope, you can use [globals()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) with [inspect.isfunction()](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction):

```
>>> def foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> def bar():
...     pass
... 
>>> import inspect
>>> [member.__name__ for member in globals().values() \
...                  if inspect.isfunction(member)]
['bar', 'foo']
```

Comment: Is there any diff. when I use 'locals()' instead of 'gloabals()' in line ::  "for member in globals().values()"
???

Comment: There won't be any difference if you run this code from the global scope, but if you run it from, say, a function, the difference should become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you want only the methods in your current context:

```
import inspect

d = locals()
funcs = [f for f in d if inspect.isfunction(d[f])]
```